# Preferred way of extracting and matching protobuf message typename from an Any package

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, packaging

I've been using `Any` to package dynamic messages for protobuf.
On the receiver end, I use `Any.type_url()` to match the enclosed message types.

Correct me if I'm wrong, knowing that `.GetDescriptor()` is unavailable with `Any`, I still want to make the matching less of a clutter. I tried to extract the message type with brute force like this:

```cpp
MyAny pouch;

// unpacking pouch
// Assume the message is "type.googleapis.com/MyTypeName"
....


const char* msgPrefix = "type.googleapis.com/";
auto lenPrefix = strlen(msgPrefix);
const std::string& msgURL = pouch.msg().type_url();
MamStr msgName = msgURL.substr(lenPrefix, msgURL.size());

if (msgName == "MyTypeName") {

   // do stuff ...

}
```

But I'm still wondering if there are cleaner way of skipping the prefix to get the "basename" of the type URL.

Thanks!

Comment: You could try 
`std::string getBaseName(std::string const & url) {
  return url.substr(url.find_last_of("/\\") + 1);
 }`
if it suits you well. Although there are some cases, it may not explode it correctly. Let's say you have two params as basename: `http://url.com/example/2` This will get the latest, which is 2... If you are not looking for cross-platform support, you can always go for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/splitpath-wsplitpath?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
std::string getBaseName(std::string const & url) { 
    return url.substr(url.find_last_of("/\\") + 1); 
}
```

if it suits you well.

Although there are some cases, it may not explode it correctly.

Let's say you have two params as basename: http://url.com/example/2

This will get the latest, which is 2...

If you are not looking for cross-platform support, you can always go for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/splitpath-wsplitpath?view=vs-2019

Comment: Ok. I thought there could be a magic helper API within protobuf, but if this is the best we could do, I'll accept this answer then. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, as I looked through the documentation, I found no helper methods/attributes or whatever that can parse anything further than `type_url()`. That's why I posted it as an answer.